# Row_number to not increment if values on three columns are the same from the row before

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, sql-server-2017, development

Suppose I have a dataset that looks like the screenshot below and I need to add a count column for the rows based off the `orderid`, `DocumentNo_`, and `CurrPackageTrackingNo` with the following logic:

- Count starts at 1
- If `orderid` is different from the `orderid` on the previous row, then the count should reset to 1.
- If the `orderid` and `DocumentNo_` is the same from the previous row but `CurrPackageTrackingNo` is different on the previous row, then the count should increment by 1
- If the `orderid`, `DocumentNo_`, and `CurrPackageTrackingNo` are all the same from the previous row, then count should remain at 1

[image]

So far Im able to get the logic on the first 3 bulletpoints using the query:

```sql
    select *
            ,row_number() over (partition by orderid order by packageNo_) as ranking
    from tblsample
    order by PackageNo_
```

But for rows 15-17 on the below screenshot, the ranking column has been incrementing when its supposed to stay at 1 for the mentioned rows. Can someone give me an insight on how I can fulfill that logic?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, what you want should be

```
dense_rank() over (partition by orderid 
                       order by DocumentNo_, CurrentPackageTrackingNo)
```